# Using PowerShell, how can I compare User Profile Properties to a list

Tags: powershell, user-profile-service

For this example, I have a list of first names

```
Fred
Mark    
Tony
Alisa
Todd
Emily
```

I would like to compare them to profiles in the user profile service

```
Fred
Greg
Tony
Alisa
John
```

And get output of all the names that are in the User Profile Service but not in the list.

```
Greg
John
```

I would like to delete those profiles that do not exist in the list. How can I do this via PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can hooked to User Profile via Powershell using following example:
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157038/accessing-sharepoint-userprofile-properties-with-powershell-script
2. Save your list in a csv file
3. Perform a for each loop from the csv file and try to find a match in user profile properties.